# Parsing error in cshtml file in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In the view, I am trying to display at most 5 images in a row. 
The idea is to introduce a new row by using the `</tr><tr>` html tags to close the present row and start a new one as shown below, but this gives a Parser error.

> Parser Error Message: The code block is missing a closing "}"
>   character.  Make sure you have a matching "}" character for all the
>   "{" characters within this block, and that none of the "}" characters
>   are being interpreted as markup.

How can I correct this?

```
<table>
    <tr>     
        @{   
            int indx = 0;
            foreach(var item in Model) { 
                indx++;                                   
                <td>
                    <a href ="@Url.Action("ShowPic", "ViewPhotos", new { id = item.ID })"> 
                        <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" /> 
                    </a>            
                    <br />                       
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption) 
                </td>
                if(indx%5==0) {
                     </tr><tr><!--Error here-->
                }

                }
            }                  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the row in question

```
@: </tr><tr><!--Error here-->
```

Because you are wrapping it in a HTML tag element, Razor cannot determine that the content within the `if` is the start of a content block. By using `@:` we are indicating that the contents of the statement should be treated as content.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `<tr>` and last `</tr>` is outside of the scope of it's opening/closing tag:

```
<table>
    @{   
        <tr>
            int indx = 0; foreach (var item in Model) { indx++;
            <td>
                <a href ="@Url.Action("ShowPic", "ViewPhotos", new { id = item.ID })">
                    <img src="@String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" />
                </a>
                <br />
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caption)
            </td>
            if(indx%5==0) {
        </tr>
        <tr>
            } }
        </tr>    
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this results in a compilation error - Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Comment: That's because it is only a snippet of the OP code. The model will of been defined in the top of the cshtml file.

Comment: Yes, the model is defined at the top of the file. How can I refer it in the scope of the snippet ?